# Magento 2 : Klarna Pay later method not appearing

Tags: magento2, sales-order, payment-methods, klarna

I am using `magento 2.4 EE` version

`Klarna` has below payment solution :

1. Pay later
2. Pay in X days (currently this one is only appearing)

I have configured klarna payment method
by following these doc steps - https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/payment/klarna-setup.html

but only `Pay in X days` is appearing not both

[image]

Comment: I am not sure why "Pay later" method not appearing